# Java get path of dir of java file where main is located

Tags: java, linux-mint

I need to get the path of a directory. The directory contains the java file where the main method is found.

So I have already searched stackoverflow but still did not find an answer.

I have already used the following but with no success:

1. `File file = new File("name.java");
       String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
       System.out.println(path);`

   Output is: /home/aaa/dev/robot/name.java
2. `String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
   System.out.println("Current working directory : " + cwd);`

   Current working directory : /home/aaa/dev/robot
3. `File resourcesDirectory = new File("src/test/resources");
   System.out.println(resourcesDirectory.getAbsolutePath());`

   /home/aaa/dev/robot/src/test/resources

What I actually need is the following:

> /home/aaa/dev/robot/src/main/java/com/aaa/robot

in which the **name.java** is found.

I am in linux mint.

Comment: **aaa** is the username. I know I am very creative

Comment: Could you explain why exactly you need the main file? Because it sounds like you think you've solved part of the problem, and want help to solve the rest. I cannot think of any scenario where you need the main file. Also, are we talking about the source file, or the compiled class file?

Comment: In this directory, there are other files that I want to read and write into. I want to run this code in different systems so that hardcoding the directory should be avoided.

Comment: @Georgios you should really, really not do that.  Rethink your solution.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I am not that experienced so I do not understand yet why this can be a problem. Do you mean, I should not read/write files located in the same directory where the main is?

Comment: @Georgios Due to the way that the classpath works in the JVM you want to consider compiled java-files (foo.class) as read-only and off-limits.  This implies that you do the same with source files (when compiling and running) as they are used to generate the class files.  You should use a folder only for these files elsewhere from the sources.  It can be located in your project folder if your version control is correctly configured.   You may want to explain in more detail what you want to do and why.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The way my project is configured is pretty random. If I remember well it was not set by default and also was not set by me. So this is the case why I cannot get the direct path with a simple way, If I understood your comment correctly. I 'll try to create a new project and test it there again. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can get the path with a relatively simple way. Questions exist on SO. It is just in my opinion not the right way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = Test.class.getName().replace(".", File.separator);
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "java" + File.separator + name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
        System.out.println(path);
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked! I still find it strange to do it like that. And do not really understand why this is the case.

Comment: @Georgios you are doing unusual thing. You have a resource next to a java class that is not good practice. you should put resource in resources directory and read them like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

Comment: This relies on the JVM having the current working directory set correctly. You cannot always assume that.

Comment: @Spara It is only for maven projects that the notion of separate resource and source folders was introduced.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes you are right and OP needs the solution on maven. I don’t really like this solution as l told OP it’s really bad practice and we should avoid it

Comment: @spara maven may be overkill for a simple IDE project but the understanding is important.

Answer (score 1):

Since the latter code was not working as expected, I updated it.

```
String canSubString = canonicalPath.substring(0,canonicalPath.lastIndexOf("/")); //+/- 1 character, just check the output.
String classname = canonicalPath.substring( canonicalPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
String command = "find " + canSubString + " -name " + classname;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

---

From here on just don't read on.

You could call the commandline tool find within your code and let it only seek there, since we assume you actually know what the Main is called.

So call in your terminal to understand what it does:

> find /home/aaa/dev/ -name "name.java"

Now, we need to combine it with Java.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find /home/aaa/dev/ -name 'name.java'");
```

You will still need to get the output though. Being not that used to calling commandline tools from Java, I'd simply write the output to a file

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find /home/aaa/dev/ -name 'name.java' > /tmp/pathtomain" );
```

At this point you will have the path you look for in /tmp/pathtomain. The /tmp folder is emptied at system shutdown by default, so no need to delete the file if this is no sensitive information.

Finally you will need to read out from that file.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/pathtomain")));
String path = "";
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
     path += scanner.nextLine() + "\n";
}
```

If the filename exists only once, then this will result in having a one-lined String. It will become more difficult, if you want to find some path to a Mainclass with some generic name like Main.

If you get more then one line you could consider regexing over it with whatever information you can extract from the code.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for since I want the code to run in different systems, so _/home/aaa/dev/_ will be different. Still I tried your code getting the following: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/pathtomain

Comment: I just updated the code. You can simply split the canonical path to use the substrings for the path and name in the find-command. This will of course only work on Unix-Systems.

Comment: @MelissaLoos  You might find https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html interesting.

Comment: @MelissaLoos using the built in cross-platform functionality is what I would expect from an experienced developer.